# Handling Notifications to Users

Tags: python, google-app-engine, notifications

I am building an application on GAE that needs to notify users when another user performs an action that affects them. A real world analogy would be being alerted when your friend comments on your facebook status.

I understand how the Channel API works to actually send notifications in real time, but I'm trying to understand the most effective way to store those notifications in the datastore. Ideally, I want the notification code to be decoupled from the actual event being performed. Is this a good use case for [Prospective Search](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/prospectivesearch/)? It doesn't quite feel right since I don't need to perform any kind of searching, just: if you see a new comment, create a new notification that is stored in the datastore and pushed to the client through the channel api if they are connected. I basically need a database trigger, but I don't think GAE supports that.

Comment: Why do feel prospective search doesn't feel right?  What criteria do other events have to match to trigger a notification?  Can you easily query for all users requiring a notification using standard queries?  If so then perform that query in a task. But it would be worth comparing the efficiency of the two methods. Prospective search queries area bit more flexible than standard queries, so the tradeoff is creating document schemas vs additional work to make standard db queries-

Comment: prospective search seems useful for streaming data as it is being created somewhere else. So, if a user performed a search, then we wanted to "keep that search running" and send new matches to the user if they occur while the user is viewing the original results. What I'm trying to do is more like a side effect of pretty much every transaction. Prospective provides a lot of flexibility that I don't need. Plus, I don't like to get tied into GAE specific features if I don't have to in case I ever need to migrate off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you want to couple the event and its notifications in the first place?
I think it may be interesting to know in order to help you with your use case :)

If I had to do this I would launch a task queue anytime I write to the datastore something that might fire events...
That way you can do your write and have a separate "layer" to process the events.
Triggers would not even be that good of an option, since your application would have to "poll" the database to push events to the users' UI.

I think your process (firing events) does not belong to the database, since it might as well need business rules that the datastore cannot provide : for example when a users ignores another one, you should not fire events.
The more business logic you put in your database system, the more complex it gets to maintain & scale IMHO...

Comment: The more I investigate this issue, the more I think it will be ok to couple these things. I don't think there's really a way around it. It seems like task queues are the way to go so that the user will not have to wait for the notification to be triggered when they perform an action. So, it's more like this: User performs action, action is stored in the database and the user is finished, action requires notifying another user, but that is just sent to a task queue so that the notification can be performed without the original user waiting.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like GAE does support mimicking database triggers using [hooks](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities#hooks).

> Hooks can be useful for
>
> 1. query caching
> 2. auditing Datastore activity per-user
> 3. **mimicking database triggers**

Comment: However these are run in the user facing transaction, which could potentially slow down the user experience if they are complex queries. Either way if you have to do a lot of notifications you will want to uses task to actually do notifications

Comment: Good point, using hooks could slow down user experience, I will look into task queues.

Comment: I found that database hooks are not really what I wanted. They don't allow me to know what has changed when the datastore object was put, so I can't send specific types of notifications depending on what was changed.